# Why My Popup Cancel Button is Not Clickable?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I Want To Handle This Popup and Click on The Cancel Button. I tried But it is Not Clickable

Image For Popup

[image: Image For Popup]

I Have Also added Html Image, Please Check and Tell Me a Solution

Image For HTML Code

[image: Image For HTML Code]

The Testcase are Passing in Selenium But it is Not Clicking.Down I Will Be Attaching The Selenium Code Also.

```
    package Backendsite;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SkipTest {
  @Test
  public void f() 
  {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");

      //Setting To Open Incoginoto Window
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.addArguments("-incognito");
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
      WebDriver chromedriver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

      chromedriver.manage().window().maximize();

      //Opening The WebSite
      chromedriver.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


      chromedriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      Pomsite p1 = PageFactory.initElements(chromedriver, Pomsite.class);

      Select s1 = new Select(p1.getE1());
      s1.selectByVisibleText("xxxxxxxxxx");

      p1.getE2().click();

      try
      {
      Actions a1 = new Actions(chromedriver);
      a1.moveToElement(p1.getE3()).click(p1.getE4()).build().perform();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          System.out.println("Can't Click");
      }

      chromedriver.close();
  }
}
```

My Second Code For Pageobject Model Class :

```
 package Backendsite;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class Pomsite 
{

    public WebElement getE1() {
        return e1;
    }

    public WebElement getE2() {
        return e2;
    }

    public WebElement getE3() {
        return e3;
    }

    public WebElement getE4() {
        return e4;
    }


    @FindBy(id="ddlstore")
    private WebElement e1;

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@id='CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_0']")
    private WebElement e2;

    @FindBy(xpath="/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]")
    private WebElement e3;

    @FindBy(xpath="/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
    private WebElement e4;



}
```

My HTML Code For Cancel Button Popup

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                <span id="prcid" style="display:none;">processing...</span>
                <button type="button" id="skipok" onclick="skipoverall(this)" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="10514438996">Ok</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
```

PS: I Also Tried With Alert and Conformation  Popup, it is Not Working.

Comment: please post html as formatted code in question rather than as image

Comment: @NitinSingh I Have Attached The HTML Code For Cancel Button as You asked.

Comment: Whether the above popup will be opened after certain action?

Comment: If not working, What is an exception its giving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class = 'modal-footer']/button[@data-dismiss = 'modal']")
private WebElement cancelButton;

Actions a1 = new Actions(chromedriver);
a1.moveToElement(p1.getCancelButton()).click(p1.getCancelButton()).build().perform();
```

PS I think I found the problem, why you are moving to `E3`, but clicking on `E4`? It could be done like this:

```
Actions a1 = new Actions(chromedriver);
a1.moveToElement(p1.getE4()).click(p1.getE4()).build().perform();
```

Comment: Actually First I Moved To The Element To The <div> Function That Was only i Mwntioned  E3 Then i  Moved and Click on the Paticular Element That i Mentioned as E4  @Andrei Suvorkov

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below by removing the try - catch block.

```
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(chromedriver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']")));
    chromedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']")).click();
```